# php preg replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to build a PHP preg replace string when processing poorly written xml, such that if I am given:

```
$x='<abc x="y"><def x="g">more test</def x="g"><blah>test data</blah></abc x="y">';
```

That it checks if there's a space within a closing tag  and deletes everything from the space to the end of the tag such that.

becomes

```
<abc x="y"><def x="g">more test</def><blah>test data</blah></abc>
```

thanks

Comment: Something like this http://snipplr.com/view/3618/close-tags-in-a-htmlsnippet/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
preg_replace('/<\/(\w+)\s*[^>]*>/', '</\1>', $x);
```

Answer (score 2):

A regex might actually be feasible in this case:

```
$xml = preg_replace("#(</(\w+:)?\w+)\s[^>]+>#", "$1>", $xml);
```

**Edit**: fixed as per @netcoder's hint. Made space mandatory before garbage.

The obvious pitfalls are of course comments (unlikely for data XML), and CDATA sections (from the looks of your xml also not likely).

Though you could still try QueryPath, it's supposed to work with XML too and might be resilient about these cases. How did it get garbled anyway?

Comment: This one will strip characters if they don't have the attribute in the closing tag. e.g.: `<foo>bar</foo>` will become `<foo>bar</fo>`.

Comment: it's a long story. But that's what I'm given. The xml won't have comments or CDATA.

Comment: @David: Actually looks like a common issue with some simpler xml-generation code. Have seen something like this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/<\/(.*?)\s+[^>]+>/', '</$1>', $string);
```

**Edit**: tested, works.

Comment: this actually almost works but fails if there are spaces within the data values - and then it removes the xml closing tag leaving an errant '>' .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_replace("/<\/((\w)([^<].*)?)\>/","</$2>",$x);
```

Code not tested

Comment: You forgot the braces around the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com):

This with @Jonah example:

```
pattern('<\/(.*?)\s+[^>]+>')->replace($string)->all()->withReferences('</$1>');
```

PS: Notice that using `with()` would quote the placeholders.